# Проблема с настройкой триггера в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

На форме есть `RadioButton` и `TextBlock`. Нужно, чтобы если у `RadioButton` свойство `IsChecked = true`, то в `TextBlock.Text` заносилась некая текстовая информация.

Следующий код не работает (*Prihod* - `RadioButton`):

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TempTxt" Text="TextBlock">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Prihod}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Приходная" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вынеси присвоение Text в стиль.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TempTxt" >
        <TextBlock.Style> 
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="TextBlock"/>
                <Style.Triggers> 
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Prihod, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="Приходная" />
                    </DataTrigger>           
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>         
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

Comment: К сожалению, тоже не работает.

Comment: Вот проект, там всё работает 
http://gfile.ru/a7JvB